# Minesweeper Action Events

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, minesweeper

Is there a way to make certain event actions specific to left and right mouse clicks?

I'm creating a minesweeper gui, so when a square is left-clicked it will be uncovered, & when it's right-clicked it will be flagged.

I wasn't sure how to syntactically check for this & couldn't find it on the tut.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've had good success using a CardLayout to best swap what the mine cells' display.  For instance, all cells initially can display a JButton whose Icon can be swapped by right mouse click via a MouseListener. Then when the button is clicked with the left mouse key (using an ActionListener) I use CardLayout to display a JLabel that either has an image icon of a mine or shows a number.

Comment: ahh dude that is really cool! Thanks for posting, I would have never thought of using a layout. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to give it a go, to try to create a simple Mine Sweeper application, one without a timer or reset (yet), but that is functional and uses both a GUI cell class and a non-GUI model class (it can't be copied and used in for intro to Java homework).

Edit 1: now has reset capability:

MineSweeper.java: holds the main method and starts the JFrame

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MineSweeper {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private MineCellGrid mineCellGrid;
   private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");

   public MineSweeper(int rows, int cols, int mineTotal) {
      mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      mineCellGrid = new MineCellGrid(rows, cols, mineTotal);

      resetButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
      resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mineCellGrid.reset();
         }
      });

      mainPanel.add(mineCellGrid);
      mainPanel.add(new JSeparator());
      mainPanel.add(new JPanel(){{add(resetButton);}});
   }

   private JPanel getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MineSweeper");
      //frame.getContentPane().add(new MineSweeper(20, 20, 44).getMainPanel());
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MineSweeper(12, 12, 13).getMainPanel());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

MineCellGrid.java: the class that displays the grid of mine cells and times them all together.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MineCellGrid extends JPanel {
   private MineCellGridModel model;
   private List<MineCell> mineCells = new ArrayList<MineCell>();

   public MineCellGrid(final int maxRows, final int maxCols, int mineNumber) {
      model = new MineCellGridModel(maxRows, maxCols, mineNumber);
      setLayout(new GridLayout(maxRows, maxCols));

      for (int row = 0; row < maxRows; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < maxCols; col++) {
            MineCell mineCell = new MineCell(row, col);
            add(mineCell);
            mineCells.add(mineCell);
            model.add(mineCell.getModel(), row, col);
         }
      }

      reset();
   }

   public void reset() {
      model.reset();
      for (MineCell mineCell : mineCells) {
         mineCell.reset();
      }
   }
}
```

MineCellGridModel.java: the non-GUI model for the MineCellGrid

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MineCellGridModel {
   private MineCellModel[][] cellModelGrid;
   private List<Boolean> mineList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
   private CellModelPropertyChangeListener cellModelPropChangeListener = new CellModelPropertyChangeListener();
   private int maxRows;
   private int maxCols;
   private int mineNumber;
   private int buttonsRemaining;

   public MineCellGridModel(final int maxRows, final int maxCols, int mineNumber) {
      this.maxRows = maxRows;
      this.maxCols = maxCols;
      this.mineNumber = mineNumber;
      for (int i = 0; i < maxRows * maxCols; i++) {
         mineList.add((i < mineNumber) ? true : false);
      }
      cellModelGrid = new MineCellModel[maxRows][maxCols];
      buttonsRemaining = (maxRows * maxCols) - mineNumber;
   }

   public void add(MineCellModel model, int row, int col) {
      cellModelGrid[row][col] = model;
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(cellModelPropChangeListener);
   }

   public void reset() {
      buttonsRemaining = (maxRows * maxCols) - mineNumber;

      // randomize the mine location
      Collections.shuffle(mineList);
      // reset the model grid and set mines
      for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
            cellModelGrid[r][c].reset();
            cellModelGrid[r][c].setMined(mineList.get(r
                     * cellModelGrid[r].length + c));
         }
      }
      // advance value property of all neighbors of a mined cell
      for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
            if (cellModelGrid[r][c].isMined()) {
               int rMin = Math.max(r - 1, 0);
               int cMin = Math.max(c - 1, 0);
               int rMax = Math.min(r + 1, cellModelGrid.length - 1);
               int cMax = Math.min(c + 1, cellModelGrid[r].length - 1);
               for (int row2 = rMin; row2 <= rMax; row2++) {
                  for (int col2 = cMin; col2 <= cMax; col2++) {
                     cellModelGrid[row2][col2].incrementValue();
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private class CellModelPropertyChangeListener implements
            PropertyChangeListener {

      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         MineCellModel model = (MineCellModel) evt.getSource();
         int row = model.getRow();
         int col = model.getCol();

         if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(MineCellModel.BUTTON_PRESSED)) {
            if (cellModelGrid[row][col].isMineBlown()) {
               mineBlown();
            } else {
               buttonsRemaining--;
               if (buttonsRemaining <= 0) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You've Won!!!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
               }
               if (cellModelGrid[row][col].getValue() == 0) {
                  zeroValuePress(row, col);
               }
            }
         }
      }

      private void mineBlown() {
         for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
               MineCellModel model = cellModelGrid[r][c];
               if (model.isMined()) {
                  model.setMineBlown(true);
               }
            }
         }

      }

      private void zeroValuePress(int row, int col) {
         int rMin = Math.max(row - 1, 0);
         int cMin = Math.max(col - 1, 0);
         int rMax = Math.min(row + 1, cellModelGrid.length - 1);
         int cMax = Math.min(col + 1, cellModelGrid[row].length - 1);
         for (int row2 = rMin; row2 <= rMax; row2++) {
            for (int col2 = cMin; col2 <= cMax; col2++) {
               cellModelGrid[row2][col2].pressedAction();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

MineCell.java: the class that I started on. Uses the model class as its non-GUI nucleus.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006029/minesweeper-action-events
 * 
 * @author Pete
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MineCell extends JPanel {
   private static final String LABEL = "label";
   private static final String BUTTON = "button";
   private static final int PS_WIDTH = 24;
   private static final int PS_HEIGHT = PS_WIDTH;
   private static final float LABEL_FONT_SIZE = (float) (24 * PS_WIDTH) / 30f;
   private static final float BUTTON_FONT_SIZE = (float) (14 * PS_WIDTH) / 30f;
   private JButton button = new JButton();
   private JLabel label = new JLabel(" ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
   private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
   private MineCellModel model;

   public MineCell(final boolean mined, int row, int col) {
      model = new MineCellModel(mined, row, col);
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPCListener());
      label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, LABEL_FONT_SIZE));
      button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
      button.setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
      setLayout(cardLayout);

      add(button, BUTTON);
      add(label, LABEL);

      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pressedAction();
         }
      });
      button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
               model.upDateButtonFlag();
            }
         }
      });
   }

   public MineCell(int row, int col) {
      this(false, row, col);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PS_WIDTH, PS_HEIGHT);
   }

   public void pressedAction() {
      if (model.isFlagged()) {
         return;
      }
      model.pressedAction();
   }

   public void showCard(String cardConstant) {
      cardLayout.show(this, cardConstant);
   }

   // TODO: have this change the button's icon
   public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
      if (flag) {
         button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
         button.setForeground(Color.red);
         button.setText("f");
      } else {
         button.setBackground(null);
         button.setForeground(null);
         button.setText("");
      }
   }

   private void setMineBlown(boolean mineBlown) {
      if (mineBlown) {
         label.setBackground(Color.red);
         label.setOpaque(true);
         showCard(LABEL);
      } else {
         label.setBackground(null);
      }
   }

   public MineCellModel getModel() {
      return model;
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      model.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   private class MyPCListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         String propName = evt.getPropertyName();
         if (propName.equals(MineCellModel.MINE_BLOWN)) {
            setMineBlown(true);
         } else if (propName.equals(MineCellModel.FLAG_CHANGE)) {
            setFlag(model.isFlagged());
         } else if (propName.equals(MineCellModel.BUTTON_PRESSED)) {
            if (model.isMineBlown()) {
               setMineBlown(true);
            } else {
               String labelText = (model.getValue() == 0) ? "" : String
                        .valueOf(model.getValue());
               label.setText(labelText);
            }
            showCard(LABEL);
         }
      }
   }

   public void reset() {
      setFlag(false);
      setMineBlown(false);
      showCard(BUTTON);
      label.setText("");
   }

}
```

MineCellModel.java: the non-GUI model for the mine cell

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

class MineCellModel {
   public static final String FLAG_CHANGE = "Flag Change";
   public static final String BUTTON_PRESSED = "Button Pressed";
   public static final String MINE_BLOWN = "Mine Blown";
   private int row;
   private int col;
   private int value = 0;
   private boolean mined = false;;
   private boolean flagged = false;
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(
            this);
   private boolean pressed = false;
   private boolean mineBlown = false;

   public MineCellModel(boolean mined, int row, int col) {
      this.mined = mined;
      this.row = row;
      this.col = col;
   }

   public void incrementValue() {
      int temp = value + 1;
      setValue(temp);
   }

   public void setValue(int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setMineBlown(boolean mineBlown) {
      this.mineBlown = mineBlown;
      PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, MINE_BLOWN, false, true);
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(evt);
   }

   public boolean isMineBlown() {
      return mineBlown;
   }

   public void setMined(boolean mined) {
      this.mined = mined;
   }

   public void setFlagged(boolean flagged) {
      this.flagged = flagged;
   }

   public int getRow() {
      return row;
   }

   public int getCol() {
      return col;
   }

   public boolean isMined() {
      return mined;
   }

   public boolean isFlagged() {
      return flagged;
   }

   public void pressedAction() {
      if (pressed) {
         return;
      }
      pressed = true;
      if (mined) {
         setMineBlown(true);
      }

      PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, BUTTON_PRESSED,
               -1, value);
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(evt);
   }

   public void upDateButtonFlag() {
      boolean oldValue = flagged;
      setFlagged(!flagged);
      PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, FLAG_CHANGE,
               oldValue, flagged);
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(evt);
   }

   public void reset() {
      mined = false;
      flagged = false;
      pressed = false;
      mineBlown = false;
      value = 0;
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }
}
```

---

---

Here's the whole program combined into a single [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) file, MineSweeper.java:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MineSweeper {
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private MineCellGrid mineCellGrid;
    private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");

    public MineSweeper(int rows, int cols, int mineTotal) {
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        mineCellGrid = new MineCellGrid(rows, cols, mineTotal);

        resetButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mineCellGrid.reset();
            }
        });

        mainPanel.add(mineCellGrid);
        mainPanel.add(new JSeparator());
        mainPanel.add(new JPanel() {
            {
                add(resetButton);
            }
        });
    }

    private JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MineSweeper");
        // frame.getContentPane().add(new MineSweeper(20, 20,
        // 44).getMainPanel());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MineSweeper(12, 12, 13).getMainPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MineCellGrid extends JPanel {
    private MineCellGridModel model;
    private List<MineCell> mineCells = new ArrayList<>();

    public MineCellGrid(final int maxRows, final int maxCols, int mineNumber) {
        model = new MineCellGridModel(maxRows, maxCols, mineNumber);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(maxRows, maxCols));

        for (int row = 0; row < maxRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < maxCols; col++) {
                MineCell mineCell = new MineCell(row, col);
                add(mineCell);
                mineCells.add(mineCell);
                model.add(mineCell.getModel(), row, col);
            }
        }

        reset();
    }

    public void reset() {
        model.reset();
        for (MineCell mineCell : mineCells) {
            mineCell.reset();
        }
    }
}

class MineCellGridModel {
    private MineCellModel[][] cellModelGrid;
    private List<Boolean> mineList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private CellModelPropertyChangeListener cellModelPropChangeListener = new CellModelPropertyChangeListener();
    private int maxRows;
    private int maxCols;
    private int mineNumber;
    private int buttonsRemaining;

    public MineCellGridModel(final int maxRows, final int maxCols, int mineNumber) {
        this.maxRows = maxRows;
        this.maxCols = maxCols;
        this.mineNumber = mineNumber;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRows * maxCols; i++) {
            mineList.add((i < mineNumber) ? true : false);
        }
        cellModelGrid = new MineCellModel[maxRows][maxCols];
        buttonsRemaining = (maxRows * maxCols) - mineNumber;
    }

    public void add(MineCellModel model, int row, int col) {
        cellModelGrid[row][col] = model;
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(cellModelPropChangeListener);
    }

    public void reset() {
        buttonsRemaining = (maxRows * maxCols) - mineNumber;

        // randomize the mine location
        Collections.shuffle(mineList);
        // reset the model grid and set mines
        for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
                cellModelGrid[r][c].reset();
                cellModelGrid[r][c].setMined(mineList.get(r * cellModelGrid[r].length + c));
            }
        }
        // advance value property of all neighbors of a mined cell
        for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
                if (cellModelGrid[r][c].isMined()) {
                    int rMin = Math.max(r - 1, 0);
                    int cMin = Math.max(c - 1, 0);
                    int rMax = Math.min(r + 1, cellModelGrid.length - 1);
                    int cMax = Math.min(c + 1, cellModelGrid[r].length - 1);
                    for (int row2 = rMin; row2 <= rMax; row2++) {
                        for (int col2 = cMin; col2 <= cMax; col2++) {
                            cellModelGrid[row2][col2].incrementValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class CellModelPropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            MineCellModel model = (MineCellModel) evt.getSource();
            int row = model.getRow();
            int col = model.getCol();

            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(MineCellModel.BUTTON_PRESSED)) {
                if (cellModelGrid[row][col].isMineBlown()) {
                    mineBlown();
                } else {
                    buttonsRemaining--;
                    if (buttonsRemaining <= 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You've Won!!!", "Congratulations",
                                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    if (cellModelGrid[row][col].getValue() == 0) {
                        zeroValuePress(row, col);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void mineBlown() {
            for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
                    MineCellModel model = cellModelGrid[r][c];
                    if (model.isMined()) {
                        model.setMineBlown(true);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void zeroValuePress(int row, int col) {
            int rMin = Math.max(row - 1, 0);
            int cMin = Math.max(col - 1, 0);
            int rMax = Math.min(row + 1, cellModelGrid.length - 1);
            int cMax = Math.min(col + 1, cellModelGrid[row].length - 1);
            for (int row2 = rMin; row2 <= rMax; row2++) {
                for (int col2 = cMin; col2 <= cMax; col2++) {
                    cellModelGrid[row2][col2].pressedAction();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MineCell extends JPanel {
    private static final String LABEL = "label";
    private static final String BUTTON = "button";
    private static final int PS_WIDTH = 24;
    private static final int PS_HEIGHT = PS_WIDTH;
    private static final float LABEL_FONT_SIZE = (float) (24 * PS_WIDTH) / 30f;
    private static final float BUTTON_FONT_SIZE = (float) (14 * PS_WIDTH) / 30f;
    private JButton button = new JButton();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel(" ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private MineCellModel model;

    public MineCell(final boolean mined, int row, int col) {
        model = new MineCellModel(mined, row, col);
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyPCListener());
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, LABEL_FONT_SIZE));
        button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
        button.setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
        setLayout(cardLayout);

        add(button, BUTTON);
        add(label, LABEL);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pressedAction();
            }
        });
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    model.upDateButtonFlag();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MineCell(int row, int col) {
        this(false, row, col);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PS_WIDTH, PS_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void pressedAction() {
        if (model.isFlagged()) {
            return;
        }
        model.pressedAction();
    }

    public void showCard(String cardConstant) {
        cardLayout.show(this, cardConstant);
    }

    // TODO: have this change the button's icon
    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        if (flag) {
            button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            button.setForeground(Color.red);
            button.setText("f");
        } else {
            button.setBackground(null);
            button.setForeground(null);
            button.setText("");
        }
    }

    private void setMineBlown(boolean mineBlown) {
        if (mineBlown) {
            label.setBackground(Color.red);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            showCard(LABEL);
        } else {
            label.setBackground(null);
        }
    }

    public MineCellModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        model.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    private class MyPCListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String propName = evt.getPropertyName();
            if (propName.equals(MineCellModel.MINE_BLOWN)) {
                setMineBlown(true);
            } else if (propName.equals(MineCellModel.FLAG_CHANGE)) {
                setFlag(model.isFlagged());
            } else if (propName.equals(MineCellModel.BUTTON_PRESSED)) {
                if (model.isMineBlown()) {
                    setMineBlown(true);
                } else {
                    String labelText = (model.getValue() == 0) ? ""
                            : String.valueOf(model.getValue());
                    label.setText(labelText);
                }
                showCard(LABEL);
            }
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        setFlag(false);
        setMineBlown(false);
        showCard(BUTTON);
        label.setText("");
    }

}

class MineCellModel {
    public static final String FLAG_CHANGE = "Flag Change";
    public static final String BUTTON_PRESSED = "Button Pressed";
    public static final String MINE_BLOWN = "Mine Blown";
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private int value = 0;
    private boolean mined = false;;
    private boolean flagged = false;
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private boolean pressed = false;
    private boolean mineBlown = false;

    public MineCellModel(boolean mined, int row, int col) {
        this.mined = mined;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public void incrementValue() {
        int temp = value + 1;
        setValue(temp);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setMineBlown(boolean mineBlown) {
        this.mineBlown = mineBlown;
        PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, MINE_BLOWN, false, true);
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(evt);
    }

    public boolean isMineBlown() {
        return mineBlown;
    }

    public void setMined(boolean mined) {
        this.mined = mined;
    }

    public void setFlagged(boolean flagged) {
        this.flagged = flagged;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public boolean isMined() {
        return mined;
    }

    public boolean isFlagged() {
        return flagged;
    }

    public void pressedAction() {
        if (pressed) {
            return;
        }
        pressed = true;
        if (mined) {
            setMineBlown(true);
        }

        PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, BUTTON_PRESSED, -1, value);
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(evt);
    }

    public void upDateButtonFlag() {
        boolean oldValue = flagged;
        setFlagged(!flagged);
        PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, FLAG_CHANGE, oldValue, flagged);
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(evt);
    }

    public void reset() {
        mined = false;
        flagged = false;
        pressed = false;
        mineBlown = false;
        value = 0;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit 1: now has reset capability and added non-GUI model for the grid.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using swing then

> Is there a way to make certain event actions specific to left and
>   right mouse clicks?

Implement a [MouseListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) no component. Then in implemented method you have a [`MouseEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) object which has a `getButton()` method which tells you which mouse is pressed.

**Edit**

OP has asked following question but now removed it.

> <del>Is this gui nested inside the other in an action event, when</del>
>   <del>game_lost becomes true?</del>

<del>You can open a JDialog for this.</del>

Comment: Thanks a ton! Right when I posted that 2nd question I saw that section in the tut, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the MouseEvent Class of java.awt.event.  [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)

Comment: The link is very old. It is for JavaSE 1.4.2.