# Please can I have some advice with my java program? void return?

Tags: java

Please can I have some help with my Java program, I have created the method below, I was just wondering how I could apply this below to my program.

The last thing to do within the model class, is to add more values to the minefield in order to determine how many mines are adjacent to any given square. Created a public method called addNumbers, which has a void return and takes no parameters.Previously, values in the_minefield take only two values, 0 (EMPTY_SQUARE) and 10 (MINE_SQUARE). Now, any empty square that is adjacent to a mine-filled square will no longer have a value of zero - it now stores the number of mines next to it. This can be any value between 1 (just one mine) and 8 (completely surrounded). Squares containing a mine still have a value of ten (MINE_SQUARE), no matter what is next to them.

//Declaration of the squares earlier on in the program:

```
 public static int MINE_SQUARE = 10;
 public static int EMPTY_SQUARE = 0;
```

//The method that needs adjusting.

```
public void addNumbers() {


 }
```

Comment: What is a square? What is "the minefield"?

Comment: a minefield is a group of squares together, such as the game of minesweeper for instance, then each individual square is used to make up the grid itself.

Answer (score 0):

When your method above is called, it iterates through the surrounding cells that are around the current cell and increment the current cell's number if the neighbor is a mine. So in pseudocode:

```
public void addNumbers() {
  loop from current row - 1 to current row + 1 taking care of *edge* cases
    loop from current col - 1 to current col + 1 taking care of *edge* cases
      if row and col are not both current row and current column
        if cell represented by row and col has a mine
          increment the current cell's number
}
```

Note that you *must* take care with edge cases -- meaning you need to know what to do when the the current cell is on the 0th row or col or on the max height row or max column col. When I've done this for my MineSweeper application, I'd declare ints as the starting and starting points of my nested for loops above the for loops and would use Math.min, Math.max to help choose my for loop limits.  So the new method would be something like this:

```
public void addNumbers() {

  declare int rowMin. Use Math.max to compare 0 and row - 1 to assign rowMin
  likewise for colMin
  likewise for rowMax, but use Math.min instead
  likewise for colMax

  loop from row = rowMin to rowMax
    loop from col = colMin to colMax
      if row and col are not both current row and current column
        if cell represented by row and col has a mine
          increment the current cell's number
}
```

Note that for my MineSweeper application, I did the exact opposite: I looped through all the cells, and if I found a mined cell, I added the mine count of all of its neighbors, but the end result would be the same:

```
public void reset() {
  buttonsRemaining = (maxRows * maxCols) - mineNumber;

  // randomize the mine location
  Collections.shuffle(mineList);
  // reset the model grid and set mines
  for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
     for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
        cellModelGrid[r][c].reset();
        cellModelGrid[r][c].setMined(mineList.get(r
                 * cellModelGrid[r].length + c));
     }
  }
  // advance value property of all neighbors of a mined cell
  for (int r = 0; r < cellModelGrid.length; r++) {
     for (int c = 0; c < cellModelGrid[r].length; c++) {
        if (cellModelGrid[r][c].isMined()) {
           int rMin = Math.max(r - 1, 0);
           int cMin = Math.max(c - 1, 0);
           int rMax = Math.min(r + 1, cellModelGrid.length - 1);
           int cMax = Math.min(c + 1, cellModelGrid[r].length - 1);
           for (int row2 = rMin; row2 <= rMax; row2++) {
              for (int col2 = cMin; col2 <= cMax; col2++) {
                 cellModelGrid[row2][col2].incrementValue();
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The link to my code is here: [Minesweeper Action Events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7016492/522444)