# Create MineSweeper-Grid from text file

Tags: java

I have to convert txt-files to a minesweepGrid-object.
These files look like this:

```
5
6
. 6 1 8 . 8
. 8 7 . 8 7
. 1 9 . 3 0
9 0 5 7 3 4
9 7 . 4 . .
```

The first two lines gives respectively the height and width of the minesweeper-board. The other lines represent the bord itself. 
The dots "." represent a mine-object. (Don't mind if the board isn't valid, for this subject the rules are sligtly modified which makes it valid, but this doesn't have to do anything with my question).

So I have following classes: minesweepGrid, NumberSpot, MineSpot .
In Numberspot I have a method getNeighbourMines() which returns a list of MineSpot-objects.
In MineSpot I have a method getNeighBourNumbers() which returns a list of NumberSpot-objects.

My question is: When I read a file and make the grid of these Number/MineSpots.
I know how to create the objects itself, but not how to configure his neighbours. What's the most efficient way to initialize the neighbourMines or neighBourNumbers-lists for each Spot?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "most efficient". How is efficiency involved here? Myself, I wouldn't worry about efficiency at all, but rather would worry about creating well crafted, easy to read, easy to debug, easy to enhance code. I'd create classes for my major nouns, including GridCell and Grid. I'd give these classes fields, such as for GridCell, boolean mined, int neighborCount, and for Grid, and array of GridCells. I'd give them methods, getters, setters,...

Comment: A way to find the surrrounding mines/numbers of a cell/spot. 
With most efficient I meant: in time.

Comment: I don't think that you really mean this, since this will never be a critical bottleneck in your program. Just keep it simple -- create and place your mines, and then loop through the grid updating the neighbor count. You could do this for each cell, counting the number of mines in its surroundings (careful of the edges and corners!), or you could do it by looping through each Mined cell, by having each mined cell call an `incrementMineCount()` method on each of its neighbors (again, careful at the edges and corners). But time efficiency has no bearhing here, no bearing whatsoever.

Comment: Please look at code that I created 4 years ago in 2011 for a similar question here: [Minesweeper Action Events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7016492/522444). In particular, please look at the `reset()` method of MineCellGridModel, especially the loops where in the inner most part I call `cellModelGrid[row2][col2].incrementValue();`. Notice how I set my inner and outer loop maximums to avoid problems at the edges and corners. As a caveat, it is old code and was created when I was just learning Java and Swing, and so there may be issues with it.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your answers. It's indeed a good way to work with min and max. Your code actually incrementsValue on the mine itself, is there a n explaination for that?

Comment: It increments the neighbor count of *all* cells. Some cells have mines on them and for them the value does not matter. You could change the code so that these cells are not incremented, or not, it will not change the outcome.